# Functions from discrete mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider the sets $A = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and $B = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$. Let $f$ be a function from $A$ to $B$, whose graph is $G = \{(0, 0), (1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 6), (4, 8)\}$.

- What is the domain and co-domain of $g(f(x))$ where $G = \{ \frac{x}{2} \}$ from $B$ to $A$
- Does the function even exist?

I have tried but since $f(5)$ to $f(9)$ does not exist, I can't figure a way to solve this problem.

Comment: $g$ is a map from $A\to A$, not from $B\to A$.

Comment: The domain of $f$ is $A$. So trying to plug in $x=5$ to $f(x)$ (and therefore also to $g(f(x))$) is not possible.

Comment: The co-domain of $f$ is $\{ 0,2,4,6,8 \} \subseteq B$ because $f: A \to B$ is defined as $2x$.

Comment: Thus, using $g := \frac x 2 : B \to A$ (and not $G = \{ \frac x 2 \}$ we have that domain of $g(f(x))$ is $\{ 0,2,4,6,8 \}$ and co-domain is $\{ 0,1,2,3,4 \}$.

Comment: But doesn't f(5) not exist and therefore does that not mean that the function is undefined ?

Comment: $f(33)$ does not exist either because $f$ is defined only on the set $A$ so it is not even legal to try it.

Comment: I'm wondering why our Teaching Assistant would even ask for such a question 3 times when all the answers are according to me 'not defined'.

Comment: By the way in the question it is writted G = {(0,0 ...... }, that is not the g function, it is the graph of ordered pairs or so.

Comment: $g$ is not the same thing as $g\circ f$.  $g:B\to A$ but $g\circ f: A\to A$. [If $h:X\to Y$ and $j:Y\to Z$ then $j\circ h:X\to Z$] So it doesn't matter that $5,9$ are not in the domain of $f$.  They aren't in the domain of $g\circ f$.  However when you write "$G= \{\frac x2\}$ from $B$ to $A$" it's not at all clear what you mean.  Is the $G$ supposed to be capital?  How does it compare to the capital $G$ meaning the graph of $f$?  Did you mean: "$g:B\to A$ is $g(x)=\lfloor \frac x2\rfloor$"?

Comment: If $h: X\to Y$ and $j: Y\to Z$ then $j\circ f: X\to Z$ and the domain of *ANY* composition of of functions $j\circ h$ is *always* the domain of $h$.  So the domain of $g\circ f$ is the domain of $f$ is $A$.  So as as $5,6,7,8,9\not \in A$ they are not in the domain of $g\circ f$ and we don't have to worry about trying to evaluate $g(f(5))$ any more that we have to worry about trying to evaluate $g(f(binky,\ the\ blue\ elephant))$.  $5,6,7,8,9$ and $binky,\ the\ blue\ elephant$ just are not in the universe of legal inputs (i.e. the domain) of $g\circ f$.